# Looping through js array and variable assignment doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a price of js code, which has been troubling  me since last few days, below is the piece of code, 
the problem is during the handling of the ajax response. The strange thing about this code is it works fine on my local machine, but does not work correctly in the online server, I have commented the issues by the code.

The strange thing about this code is , when I put it up online, the `currField` and the `tempfieldDivId` variables don't work at all and the `temp` variable(which I added for debugging) is printed in the alert with the correct value. But it fails in the switch case.
And in the switch it always falls to the the default option  and prints "No match" .

```
 $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "components/form/form_processing.php",
                data: dataStringfrmFlds,
                cache:false,
                success: function(opt){

                    alert(opt);// opt is fine, returns:  ship_to,first_notify_party,consignee,shipment_type,packaging_requirements,testing_requirements,date,request_expected_date,order_ponunber

                    var defaultFields = opt.split(',');
                    var numFields = defaultFields.length;

                    for(i = 0; i < numFields; i++){
                          var temp              = "";   

                          var currField         = defaultFields[i];
                          var tempfieldDivId    = "def_"+currField;

                          //these doesnt work
                          $(tempfieldDivId).show();
                          $('#'+currField).attr('required','required');

                           temp = currField;
                           alert(temp); //this does print the field name in the alert   

                           //these doesnt work either      
                           switch(temp){

                                 case "os_id":
                                 $("#def_os_id").show();
                                 break;

                                 case "ff_id":
                                 $("#def_ff_id").show();
                                 break;

                                 case "fnp_id":
                                 alert("HI there");
                                 $("#def_fnp_id").show();
                                 break;

                                 case "cinfo_id":
                                 $("#def_cinfo_id").show();
                                 break;

                                 case "order_date":
                                 $("#def_order_date").show();
                                 break;

                                 case "order_shiptype":
                                 $("#def_order_shiptype").show();
                                 break;

                                 case "order_portdis":
                                 $("#def_order_portdis").show();
                                 break;

                                 case "order_requestform":
                                 $("#def_order_requestform").show();
                                 break;

                                 case "order_specialinstructions":
                                 $("#def_order_specialinstructions").show();
                                 break;

                                 case "order_packreq":
                                 $("#def_order_packreq").show();
                                 break;

                                 case "order_testreq":
                                 $("#def_order_testreq").show();
                                 break;

                                 case "order_reqexdate":
                                 $("#def_order_testreq").show();
                                 break;

                                 default:
                                alert("No match");//this is printed out all the times
                                 break;
                               }//end of switch
                        }//end of for loop
                  }
            });
```

I would be very grateful if anyone can help me on this. Thank you.

Comment: Console log `defaultFields` and have a look at the inside of the array. Does it show properly ?

Comment: print that array in console log..because it looks fine to me...this should work..

Comment: i think cases are different compare to defaultFields values...i am saying this because you have written defaultFields value at top which is different compare to cases.

Comment: thanks everybody, I am working on the suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `$(tempfieldDivId).show();` do you need to add a "#" before tempfieldDivId?
2. `opt` is 
   `ship_to,first_notify_party,consignee,shipment_type,packaging_requirements,testing_requirements,date,request_expected_date,order_ponunber`
   I didn't see any of them match any case in your `switch` statement, of course it will fall down to default every time.

Comment: @wong2 this was very helpful , yep, I overlooked adding the # before tempfieldDivId. But I don't understand why the switch will fall down to default. If you could elaborate it would be wonderful.

Comment: aaah! I see it I have been so dumb!I will check the variables and the switch cases.

Comment: @pillar.of.autumn `switch` will compare the variable `tmp`(which is an element from `defaultFields `) to its `case` from up to down until a match happen, and if no `case` match `tmp`, it will fall to `default`. (according to the value of `opt ` you gave, this is what's happening)

Comment: at last , it got solved, so basically I entirely overlooked the server response, which was different in case of the local machine  and the online server.  Local machine `os_id,fnp_id,cinfo_id,order_shiptype,order_requestform,order_date,order_reqexdate` which is correct , online server `ship_to,first_notify_party,consignee,shipment_type,packaging_requirements,testing_requirements,date,request_expected_date,order_ponunbe` which is wrong, so I undated the data in the db and now everything is fine, thanks everybody very much and specially to wong and vivek  for pointing out the bug is switch